# Azure Functions App Full Log

Tags: javascript, azure, debugging, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions app that I recently spun up which runs on a time trigger 4 times a day. The problem that I am running into is that I cannot find full log file for each runtime. The logs under monitor tab in the Azure portal only show the log up to a certain number of lines, and the log files in the Kudu console only save if I run the function myself via the portal. Judging by the fact that the monitor tab has the first few lines of each log, I would assume that they are being saved somewhere, but I can't seem to find out where. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invocation logs that you see in the portal are stored in Table Storage:

[image: Logs in Table Storage]

If your log is longer than the maximum which is allowed by Table Storage column, it will be truncated.

If that is the case, go to `App Settings` -> `Diagnostics logs` and enable logging to Filesystem and/or Blob storage, where the full log will be available.

For Blob storage, the logs will be placed to `$logs` container:

[image: Logs in Blob Storage]

You can navigate both Table Storage and Blobs with [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).

Comment: How did you get to this view? Is this for webJobs?

Comment: That's Azure Storage Explorer, added a link in my answer.

Comment: `$logs` is storage diagnostics, it's not where the function writes to. There should be a different container for that, probably the one below it. But there's Application Insights integration now for Functions, just enable it, no one should be fiddling with Table or Blob logs. How would you even query those... it's not trivial, tons of friction and little context.